# How to rewrite a Javascript If-Statement to select Classes instead of ID's in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, optimization

I have a working javascript that is just very not elegant and cumbersome:

```
//check if certain div (with higher main id) is clicked and then run a script

if (item.content.attr("id") == 'gridgallery1') {
  $('#grid1').grid();   // GALLERY initialisaion
} 
if (item.content.attr("id") == 'gridgallery2') {
  $('#grid2').grid();   // GALLERY initialisaion
}
if (item.content.attr("id") == 'gridgallery3') {
  $('#grid3').grid();   // GALLERY initialisaion
}
```

Accompanying working HTML code:

```
<div id="gridgallery1">
  <div id="grid1" data-directory="IMAGES/FIRST GALLERY"></div>
</div>

<div id="gridgallery2">
 <div id="grid2" data-directory="IMAGES/SECOND GALLERY"></div>
</div>

<div id="gridgallery3">
  <div id="grid3" data-directory="IMAGES/THIRDGALLERY"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Question 1.** I want to rewrite the above If-Statements in one short elegant If-Statement, be true for all cases covering anything from `'grid1'` and `'gridgallery1'` all the way to `'grid99'` and `'gridgallery99'`) How to rewrite the above If-Statement?

---

**Question 2.** Perhaps the better way would be to have multple classes instead of ids. I thought I could change the "id" to "class" sothat I don't need to change the html code in the first place for every added gallery container, but if I change:

`if (item.content.attr("id")`
 into 
`if (item.content.attr("class")`

then it doesn't work anymore! What I really want is simply a javascript If statement that finds all these instances and (all divs with these classes) and runs the script.

```
<div class="gridgallery">
  <div class="grid" data-directory="IMAGES/FIRST GALLERY"></div>
</div>

<div class="gridgallery">
  <div class="grid" data-directory="IMAGES/SECOND GALLERY"></div>
</div>

<div class="gridgallery">
  <div class="grid" data-directory="IMAGES/THIRDGALLERY"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** 
Assuming that in `item.content` you store a jQuery-selected element:

```
$('#grid' + item.content.attr('id').split('gridgallery')[1] ).grid();
```

**Question 2:**

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you should read about some handy jQuery methods such as `$('#someElement').hasClass('some-class')` which returns `true` or `false`

Comment: please see updated question 2 mate.  Do I replace the entire if statement with your single line? (that doesn't work). I thought the solution came in an "if-statement" form. Thanks!

Comment: no if's needed! this line just calls `grid()` on #grid + whatever comes after gridgallery. Look up how `.split()` works to better understand.

Answer (score 1):

With the HTML you show under "Question 2", you should be able to replace the if-statements with the following line:

```
item.content.find('.grid').grid(); // GALLERY initialisaion
```

Comment: thanks but it's unclear for me which part to replace in the javascript exactly, please suggest the rewritten javascript

Comment: @Sam - That is the rewritten JavaScript. As I say in my answer, you can replace the if-statements with that line of code.